# Why did Trump fire all members of the PACHA?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, healthcare, republican-party

Recently, Trump fired all members of his AIDS/HIV council (PACHA).

Why would anyone actively choose to shut down a council on an important health issue?

Comment: To clarify, has Trump fired the members of the council to replace them with his own appointees, or has he disbanded the council?

Answer (score 10):

Barack Obama did the [same thing](http://www.newsweek.com/trump-fires-hivaids-council-its-entirety-fedex-letter-report-claims-763737) when he took office:

> The decision by an administrator to clear house at PACHA is not unprecedented. The Obama administration eliminated all of George W. Bush’s appointees in the same way.

The main reason seems to have been to replace the Bush advisors with his own.  Perhaps Donald Trump wishes to do the same thing.

It is quite possible that Trump fired them because some have been publicly critical of him.  He has been known to punish public disloyalty (and he considers public criticism as disloyal) this way in other cases.

It is worth noting that we don't actually know, as the Trump administration has not given a reason.  So any answer is going to be a bit speculative.